# How to measure DispatchQueue back pressure

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, backpressure

My program has many parallel processes each on their own queue. I'd like to be able to visualize/measure the back pressure of the queues.

One approach is to count every block that enters and exits, but I'm sure GCD has this information already. Is there a better approach to measuring back pressure?

Comment: Do you you mean like https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/#/dev44b2b437 ?

Comment: @matt Instruments is only after the fact or while connected to a debug app, I was looking for a production solution. The measurements will be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for querying the number of pending blocks in a GCD queue. That said, since you're asking about a queue that you "own", you can wrap it in a way that lets you keep track of that. For instance, you could make your own wrappers around `dispatch_[a]sync` that would increment a counter whenever you enqueued a block, and also wrapped the block to decrement the counter when the block completes. This really wouldn't be that hard to implement. (`dispatch_queue_get_specific` would likely be a good place to start...)

FWIW, a few years back, I would've suggested you use `NSOperationQueue`, but even `NSOperationQueue` has deprecated its `operationCount` property, so it's probably fair to say that Apple is unlikely to provide this functionality going forward, so implementing it yourself is probably your best option, if you really need this functionality.

This is probably not immediately helpful to you, but if you need to measure "back pressure" on GCD queues, you're probably not using them in the right way. If you're enqueuing work items that block during execution, that's bad, and will eventually lead to thread starvation. If you're enqueuing tons of work items that you might want to cancel, say if the user changed screens or something, then you should work on a pattern for cancellable work items (or use `NSOperation`). I'm struggling to think of a use case that would demand that you be able to measure "back pressure" that couldn't be solved with your own code.

Comment: Wrapping the queues was my initial thought, and I think the final solution. However, it adds an additional function call, maybe the counting could be inlinable. It's many very performance critical tasks, so any overhead compounds. The project is pure swift, no NSFoundation or any ObjC because of method lookup costs, and everything is value types and immutable. Just trying to squeeze out every ms.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the overhead of wrapping `dispatch_*` calls to keep track of a count is going to pale in comparison to the expense of GCD managing and scheduling your work items. You say you're doing "many perf critical tasks" and that "overhead compounds". Have you considered trying to bundle a number of small tasks into a smaller number of larger tasks to limit the queue management overhead? I don't know for sure, and GCD is pretty good, but my gut tells me that queue mgmt overhead is going to dwarf the overhead of a counter inc/decrement and an extra function call or two.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. The application is processing real time information. Batching would mean a delay, and the data can't be dropped and the goal is near realtime processing. Honestly, I think even my laptop's processor will be more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to visualize what is going on, you can use [`OSLog`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslog/), post `.begin` and `.end` events and watch it in Instruments’ “Points of Interest”. (See WWDC 2019 [Getting Started with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/).)

So, import `os.log`:

```swift
import os.log
```

Then create a log:

```swift
private let pointsOfInterestLog = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: .pointsOfInterest)
```

Enqueue 100 tasks:

```swift
for i in 0..<100 {
    enqueueTask(i) {
        print("done \(i)")
    }
}
```

Where the routine posts a `.begin` event to the points of interest log before dispatching the task, and posts a `.end` event when the task actually starts, e.g.

```swift
func enqueueTask(_ index: Int, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let id = OSSignpostID(log: pointsOfInterestLog)
    os_signpost(.begin, log: pointsOfInterestLog, name: "backlog", signpostID: id, "queued %d", index)

    queue.async {
        os_signpost(.end, log: pointsOfInterestLog, name: "backlog", signpostID: id, "started %d", index)
        ...
        completion()
    }
}
```

Then profile the app (with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or “Product” » “Profile”) and choose, for example, “Time Profiler” (which includes the “Points of Interest” tool). Start a recording an you will see a visual representation of your backlog:

[image]

(I expanded the “Points of Interest” to be big enough to show all 100 backlogged tasks.)

This is one way to visualize your backlog. I must confess that I generally use “Points of Interest” not to show the backlog, but rather to show when these tasks are actually running (i.e. `.begin` when the dispatched task actually starts running and `.end` when the dispatched task finishes). Or I use the “thread” view in Instruments to see how my worker threads are being used. Or I use the “CPU” view in Instruments to see how my CPUs are being used.

Regardless, as you can see, Instruments can be used to visualize whatever time ranges you want, in this case, the time between the adding of the task to the queue and when it starts running.

Comment: Very detailed! I was looking for a production solution so I can display the back pressure live. But what you showed with signposts also gives a per block processing time, really useful. I didn't know it was this easy, I'll add signpost as well for sure.